# Special search and replace software

Tags: search

I want to search and replace multiple words at once.

I know there's a software for this but the additional thing that I want is for example: I want to replace "add" with "include" then replace "include" with "add" but I don't want the first replaced word to change with the second replacement.

I know it's crazy but is there a software or anything that I can do that with?

I have already tried Office-word Search and replace software and it can't do what I want.

Comment: For Windows? In which files are these words?

Comment: Without "special software", that should be achievable with 3 steps: 1) replace "add" with e.g. "§§§tmp§§§" (or any other term not being used elsewhere), 2) replace "include" with "add", 3) replace "§§§tmp§§§" with "include". Done.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways (that I know of) to accomplish this,

1. (Provided by @Izzy)

   1. Replace "add" with "$#$one$#$"
   2. Replace "include" with "add"
   3. Replace "$#$one$#$" with "include"
2. (Provided by [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/211011/find-and-replace-several-several-different-values-all-at-once)) -Requires [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

   1. Search -> Replace
   2. Find what: (add)|(include)
   3. Replace with: (?1include)(?2add)
   4. Click "Replace All"

[image: Before text]

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2 through 4]

[image: After text]